# How do I add a static block to 1column, 2columns and 3 columns all pages?

Tags: xml, static-block

I created a static block that I want to add in all of the 1,2,3columns pages from pages. Where should I include this xml code?

```
   <reference name="content">
                <block type="cms/block" name="home_banner" before="-">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>top_banner</block_id></action>
                </block> 
   </reference>
```

This block should be editable from admin panel so I cannot use : `getChildHtml` function.

**UPDATE**. If I use this code in the 1,2,3 column phtml files

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header_robey_banner')->toHtml(); ?>
```

it works. BUt can it be done by using just xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to call this static block to all layout then you ***need to add your code in default  handler*** `<default></default>`.

This handler ***is called on all frontend page*** .*It does not matter whatever page layout is*

> ```
> <default><!-- this call default handler -->
> <reference name="content">
>                 <block type="cms/block" name="home_banner" before="-">
>                     <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>top_banner</block_id></action>
>                 </block> 
>    </reference>
> </default>
> ```

You need to call this ***code at local.xml or any  exiting layout files st your Template folder*** (`app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/layout`)

If you local.xml exit at then it code should be like

(`app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/layout`)

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <layout version="0.1.0">
> <default><!-- this call default handler -->
> <reference name="content">
>                 <block type="cms/block" name="home_banner" before="-">
>                     <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>top_banner</block_id></action>
>                 </block> 
>    </reference>
> </default>
> </layout>
> ```

Comment: I put it in my local.xml from my theme, and it is not work. Am i missing smth ?

Answer (score 0):

if you create the local.xml then add in this inside the `<global></global>` tag.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml
```

else add in your page.xml

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml
```

Comment: so <layout><default><global>....</global></default></laypout> in this order ?

Comment: yes this is the order..